# Twitter bootstrap tooltip inside x-handlebars template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I have a **Handlebars Template**

```
<script id="line_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  .....
  <td>{{OrderDateString}}</td>
  <td>{{StoreName}}</td>
  <td><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">{{CommissionString}}</a></td>
  .....
</script>
```

and a **Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").tooltip({
      'selector': '',
      'placement': 'bottom'
    });
  });
</script>
```

All is working fine except the Bootstrap tooltip.
Outside the handlebar template the Bootstrap tooltip is working, so I know everything is loaded correctly.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: This has nothing to do with c#.

Comment: Can you provide a example of the problem using JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're binding it on document ready, it may not be binding to the elements being created when the handlebars template renders. I fixed this by binding the tooltip behaviour after rendering the template.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if it's this simple but it seems that you need to add a `data-toggle` attribute to your anchor so it looks like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">{{CommissionString}}</a></td>
```

I notice the question is pretty old, so it's a good idea to start posting questions with your version of Bootstrap or what not so even though these questions get a bit buried, if someone finds them they are more likely to find a valid answer.